# Fail to login after deploying a site to production

Tags: php, laravel

I have a site created using laravel as backend, when the project is in localhost work fine but after deploying to a live server I experience this error. Please any help

Here is the error:

> Target class [App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated] does not exist.

And below is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect($guard.'/dashboard');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you serving the application on your production environment?

Comment: I have hosted under public_html to one of the paid server

Comment: Can you please share the whole Middleware code?

Comment: @Shrey I have shared the whole Middleware

Comment: did you run composer install  &  composer dumpautoload commands on your production?

Comment: You placed the whole laravel project in `public_html`?

Comment: what is the exact filename and path for this class that isn't loading?

Comment: You shouldn't drop your laravel app under the public_html folder, instead delete it and create a symlink with the same name pointing to /public.

Comment: I got this message after running dump-autoload in console

Class App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated located in ./app/Http/Middleware/AdminRedirectifAuthenticated.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.